# css class makes html element disappear

Tags: html, css

I have an html element which is an image 
. There is no problem seeing the image in mobile, but when you look at the page in computer, the image disappears.
I found out the reason this element disappears is when I give it a class="ad_img".
there is no style for appearing and disappearing this element inside that class.
When I remove class="ad_img" the image shows up.

```css
.ad_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.ad_main_div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.ad_main_panel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="ad_main_div">
    <p> With class </p>
    <button id="ad_main_button" class="ad_main_panel">
          <img src="https://pearlcapital.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/FB-Phone-GIF.gif"   id="ad_main_img" alt="No Image" class="ad_img"/>                 
    </button>
    
    <p> Without class </p> 
     <button id="ad_main_button" class="ad_main_panel">
          <img src="https://pearlcapital.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/FB-Phone-GIF.gif" id="ad_main_img" alt="No Image" />                 
     </button>
  </div>
</center>
```

[image]

[image: screenshot of img element in mobile browser]

Comment: Does this edit reproduce the issue for you? I can't see the issue on my computer.

Comment: I editted your question and coverted your html css into a code snippet. Does it reproduce the problem? If not can you edit the question so that it does?

Comment: @dwjohnston thank you so much, you can see the change, with and without the class in snippet

Comment: Can you post a ascreen shot of what you see.

Comment: For me, when you remove the class you see the whole image, rather than having it truncated. 

But that makes sense - because you have some extra styling for the image that comes from the `.ad_img` class styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that your ad blocker is is preventing the image from displaying.

The ad blocker is using the the `ad_img` class to find the element to block.

When I disable my blocker the image displays.

[image]

This also explains why it works on your phone, as your phone browser likely doesn't have an ad blocker.

Comment: that is true, so the solution is, changing the class name i guess.

Comment: Just disable your ad blocker for development and show case. You can change the class name, but my guess is that it will just be black listed again. If you're trying to make ads displays despite an ad blocker being in place, that would be a whole endevor, which AFAIK people haven't solved, because I don't see ads when I browser the internet with an ad blocker on.

Comment: Actually i am not showing a google ad or anything. I was loading an image from mysql database, but the only thing that made ad blocker block it was the name "ad"  at the begaining of the class.

Comment: @DrustTaib Ok sure, yeah, so changing the class name is probably a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any javascript running in the page changing display to none or visibility to hidden?

The code snippet runs fine here also.

Comment: The ad blocker :)